# Calculating $E[exp(\int_0^T W_s dW_s)]$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

By using Ito's Formula I was able to calculate $\int_0^T W_t dW_t = \frac {W^2_T} 2 - \frac T 2$, after this how to proceed in order to calculate Expected value , I know that: 
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} exp⁡(X)f(x)dx$$

Comment: It suffices to compute $E[e^{X^2/2}]$ where $X$ is $N(0,T)$ distributed.

Comment: I followed your hint and my answer comes out to be  e^-T/2{((\frac{1}{\sqrt T}) - 1)}, don't know whether it is right.